# Selenium IDE and CKEditor

Tags: selenium, ckeditor

I want to cleanup some HTML in a database using CKEditor's cleanup process.  I need it to use this exact cleanup algorithm for reasons that are beyond the scope of this question. Submitting an existing form works perfectly, however there are many rows in the table, making for a tiresome process if done manually.

The solution I came up with was to generate a Selenium IDE test case that simply loads the page then submits the form for each record in the database.

The problem is that when Selenium IDE saves the data it does not seem to apply CKEditor's HTML cleanup algorithm.

For example...

I have the following in my database (loaded into CKEditor) when the form is loaded:

```
<p>
Hello World
</p>
```

When I press save on the form, the following is the result in my database:

```
<p>Hello World</p>
```

When I run a Selenium IDE script to load the page and submit the form, however the HTML remains unchanged (the cleanup did not occur).

Here is an example of my selenium script for a single form:

```
<table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" border="1">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="1" colspan="3">selenium ckeditor</td>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>open</td>
    <td>/form.php?id=1</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>fireEventAndWait</td>
    <td>id=form</td>
    <td>submit</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

It seems some JS event is not being triggered, but I am not sure which event it could be.

Comment: Just guessing here, but could it be that Selenium IDE records form submissions and not the act of entering a certain input into inputs? Also, could you clean up the html from the selenium script? :)

Comment: @Motin - I tried code to click into the field and enter the current value, but I couldn't get it to work, and I assumed that was not the case because it does do some HTML updating, for example it will strip away the span tags from `<p><span style="line-height:1.6em"></span></p>`.

Comment: found that if I issue a 1 second pause after loading the page it works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pausing for a second after loading the page makes it work.  I guess selenium was submitting before ckeditor kicked in.

```
<table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" border="1">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="1" colspan="3">selenium ckeditor</td>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>open</td>
    <td>/form.php?id=1</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>pause</td>
    <td>1000</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>fireEventAndWait</td>
    <td>id=form</td>
    <td>submit</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```